# if statement in ng-repeat directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, if-statement, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the template:

```
            <div ng-repeat="CableFilterName in CableFilterNames">

                <fieldset>
                  <legend>{{CableFilterName.filterName}}</legend>
                  <ul id="">
                    <li ng-repeat="filterValue in CableFilterName.filterValues">
                        <input type="checkbox"/> {{filterValue}}
                        <!-- <select> -->
                    </li> 

                  </ul>
                </fieldset>

               </div>
```

where `filterValue` in nested `ng-repeat` has several different values. So question is how to define what is current `filterValue`-value and depending on it use checkbox or select or any arbitrary HTML ?

**UPD**:

```
filterValues = ['Cable System','Electrical', 'Lighting'];
```

Comment: `ng-repeat has several different values`, please give ana example of different values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a kind of if statement, you can use the ngSwitch directive in AngularJS :

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch)

For example on your ngRepeat loop :

```
<div ng-switch on="filterValue">
     <div ng-switch-when="value1">//Do what you want when "value1"</div>
     <div ng-switch-when="value2">//Do what you want when "value2"</div>
     ...
     <div ng-switch-default>//Do what you want by default</div>
</div>
```

I Hope it's what you want, I don't really understand what you try to achieve.